# Google speech to text API does not return anything not even an error

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, google-speech-to-text-api

I tried to get the text from a random youtube video just to try out the API but it does not return anything. It does workwhen using the sample file 'audio.raw' from this repository.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/speech/testdata

The youtube video i'm using : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liAsT4DqalQ
The english is pretty clear and the audio version i have locally is clear. The file is of type webm maybe this is the problem,  i tried with a m4a file but no luck :x

My code is just like the one from the async simple, the really weird part is that i do not get any error...

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    speech "cloud.google.com/go/speech/apiv1"
    speechpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/speech/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := speech.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req := &speechpb.LongRunningRecognizeRequest{
        Config: &speechpb.RecognitionConfig{
            Encoding:        speechpb.RecognitionConfig_LINEAR16,
            SampleRateHertz: 16000,
            LanguageCode:    "en-US",
        },
        Audio: &speechpb.RecognitionAudio{
            AudioSource: &speechpb.RecognitionAudio_Uri{Uri: "gs://BUCKET_NAME/eng.webm"},
        },
    }

    op, err := client.LongRunningRecognize(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    resp, err := op.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Print the results.
    for _, result := range resp.Results {
        for _, alt := range result.Alternatives {
            fmt.Printf("\"%v\" (confidence=%3f)\n", alt.Transcript, alt.Confidence)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, made it work by switching to aws

Comment: I'm bookamrking this

Comment: That's how I resolve my Google Cloud issues as well